# Python - Removing whitespace on output

Tags: python, whitespace, removing-whitespace

So, I have this code:

```
print("%d" % a, end=(" "))
```

It works, but in the output, there's a whitespace after the last number. I need to get rid of the last whitespace. My output needs to be shown on the same line, separated by a blank space. There should be no space after the last value.

Here's an example: (n is input, so suppose n = 5)

```
0 1 1 2 3
```

I've tried .strip, .join, but none of them worked. What do i have to do to get the right output? I'm sorry if this is too much of a simple question, I'm new in python.

edit: edit2:

```
a, b, i = 0, 1, 0
n=int(input())
for j in range(0, n):
    while i < n:
        print("%d" % a)
        a, b = b, a + b
        i += 1
```

Comment: is `a` a list? Whats the input for `a`? Please, edit your question and add more information about your input in order to understand what are you looking for.

Comment: what do you think `end=(" ")` does?

Comment: See my updated answer. Also, please include all relevant code in your question to make it obvious what you are trying to do.

Comment: thanks, elethan! that was really helpful. its fixed  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the trailing space yourself with the `end` argument.

```
print("%d" % a, end=(" "))
```

Means print `a` ending in a `' '`. Remove the `end` argument and the trailing space will no longer be printed (the default `'\n'` will be printed instead). See [the docs for `print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) for more details.

Note also, that the `end` argument does not affect the string you are printing, i.e., `a` is not affected by `end`. If there is a trailing space in a string `a`, then `a.strip()` will remove that space. The reason it doesn't get removed by `strip()` in your case is that the space is not in the string you are printing, but instead is added to the visual output by the `print()` function.

## Update:

It is hard to say, because it is a mystery what happens before or after the code snippet in your edit, but it sounds like you want to do something like:

```
a, b, i = 0, 1, 0
n=int(input())
nums = []
for j in range(0, n):
    while i < n:
        nums.append(str(a))
        ...
        # Based on your desired output, 
        # I assume you modify the value of `a` somwhere in here
        ...
print(' '.join(nums))
```

Comment: but if i remove the end=(" ") my output is like

Comment: + one number each line

Comment: Put the input values, converted to strings in a [ list ] then " ".join(list)